# Android WhatsApp do voice call

Tags: android

I want to start voice call via WhatsApp from my application without entering WhatsApp chat window. Here's my code:

```
    Uri mUri = Uri.parse("tel:" + getPhoneNumber(contactName, context));
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, mUri);
    mIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(mIntent);
```

where getPhoneNumber(contactName, context) returns phone number as String. It works well for android.phone app, but not for whatsapp

Comment: Well, this doesn't work like that. AFAIK they dont support that intent

Comment: well, is there any other way to start call with whatsapp? Not by using that intent

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a method to do the start call and capturing the event: state of call, and hangup event, and also a method to simulate voice from microphone, but this kind of project need a new whole of project customization and android modification.

the hint is do Java Reflection Method to initialize a Object/Class and invoke method to do the call,